# Jenkins File Paramter - Excel File getting corrupted when using as input to File Parameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized job, where by I upload an Excel worksheet.

This Excel worksheet is my input to a step where some automation will be done on the test data.

The excel file gets copied to the workspace in jenkins, but is getting corrupted because of which it is does not remain usable or accessbile.

Comment: The pipeline is made in UI.

Comment: Please share your code and elaborate on the issue.

Comment: The pipeline is created from UI. I have added a file parameter. when I execute the build, it gives me an option to upload a file, where I upload the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood the root cause.

The workspace folder has a read only access. If we move this file to some other location outside of Jenkins workspace, the file is OK.

I got the workaround to access the file, I now only read the file instead of moving it.

Note :Even if I try to change the permissions of the folder, the same permissions again come back.